# How do I launch clients on different event loops?

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertxoptions

I am creating a testing application that suppose to have many connections to a server. When I create a client from my Verticle it is always processing the connection and messages on the same tread.

When I created my verticle I set

options.setEventLoopPoolSize(4)

So I would it expect it to round robin to the 4 event loops because I want to have millions of connections.

I'm doing

```
        launch {
            val socket = netClient.connectAwait(port, host)
            log.info().log("connected on - {} {}", Thread.currentThread(), Vertx.currentContext())
            socket.handler {
                log.info().log("{}", it)
            }
        }
```

2019-06-04 17:30:06,479 INFO  [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] MainVerticle: connected on - Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext@150049b3

Always on same thread.... How do I launch the connection on different event-loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, creating many connections from a single host is a mistake. You'll get into a bottleneck on your client machine probably long before you overload your server.

Second, creating your own load test tool is a mistake. There are excellent tools available for that already, like [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk), which solved many problems you'll have.

Now, to the question at hand. Connections are launched on different threads of the event loop. You can see it running the following code:

```
private const val port = 8443

fun main() {
    val counter = AtomicLong(0)
    val vertx = Vertx.vertx()
    val client = vertx.createNetClient()
    var timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
    vertx.createNetServer().connectHandler { ctx ->
        counter.getAndIncrement()
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp > 1000) {
            println(counter.get())
            counter.set(0)
            timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }
        ctx.end()
    }.listen(port)

    println("Server started")

    ddos(client)
}

fun ddos(client: NetClient) {
    for (i in 0..999999) {
        client.connect(port, "localhost") {
            println(Thread.currentThread().name)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you'll also get much more threads:

```
vert.x-eventloop-thread-14
vert.x-eventloop-thread-12
vert.x-eventloop-thread-10
vert.x-eventloop-thread-14
vert.x-eventloop-thread-14
vert.x-eventloop-thread-10
```

Also note that you don't actually need to use coroutines for that.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working, I think the problem I was having is that I was already within a verticle context while in your example you are not inside a verticle